# How to list just people managers?

Tags: sql

How can I query just a list of people managers? I tried using Distinct to no avail. Here is a snapshot of my data:
I have the persons GNumber (like an ID) and the person's managerGNumber which should make this doable. Thank you.

```
First    Last        Gnumber     Department            ManagerGNumber   Title
Alex     Anderson    G000001     Corp                                   CEO
Brooke   Brown       G000002     Accounting            G000001          VP
Carol    Clark       G000003     Marketing             G000001          VP
David    Drew        G000004     Human Resources       G000001          VP
Walter   Watson      G000005     Finance               G000001          VP
Erin     Eisley      G000006     Tables                G000002          Director
Felicia  Ford        G000007     Accounting            G000002          Director
Grace    Griffin     G000008     IT                    G000003          Director
Henry    Howard      G000009     Sales                 G000003          Director
Ian      Iverson     G000010     Product Development   G000004          Director
Janice   Jones       G000011     Operations            G000004          Sr. Architect
Xenon    Xandruski   G000012     Sales                 G000005          Director
Karl     King        G000013     Human Resources       G000006          Sales Rep
Mike     Miller      G000014     Sales                 G000007          Sales Rep
Linda    Lewis       G000015     Accounting            G000006          Sales Rep
Nancy    Nash        G000016     Sales                 G000007          Sales Rep
```

Comment: I don't understand.. what query did you try? How does this relate to coldfusion? Your question is unclear.

Comment: You're missing a lot of info. What do the IDs mean? What's the ID of a manager?

Comment: John - This is purely a SQL question. However, you have not clearly demonstrated the problem you are having. We need to see 1) the SQL you tried, 2) the *actual* results and 3) the results you *expected* instead. (See [Ask]). Also, sql syntax can vary depending on the DBMS, so always include your database type/version in any sql questions.

Comment: Guys, I apologize for the poorly worded question. I am going to take your advice and go back to the SQL book. Buzz's answer did work for what I'm trying to do but your points remain valid. Thank you. - John M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your underlying database is SQL based, if you can somehow get to this, then it yields just the people who are not represented in the ManagerGnumber column:

```
select * 
from yourTable 
where Gnumber in (
    select distinct(ManagerGnumber) 
    from yourTable
);
```

Comment: I think John should at least try to write some SQL